# Laptop compatibility

Tags: 14.04, graphics, asus

I am looking at purchasing an Asus k55vd-dh71-ca and installing Ubuntu 14.04 on it as my OS. I will probably start with a dual boot just to be safe, but I was wondering if anyone has used 14.04 on this laptop and what the successes and problems were. Frankly, I just want to make sure that Ubuntu 14.04 will work with this unit. This laptop does use nVidea and integrated Intel graphics, so I also want to make sure that I can run the nVidea graphics full time, or at even be able to switch between the two depending on my needs at the time.
Any input is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You better ask this type of questions at ubuntuforums. It is off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a hardware compatibility issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are several Linux probes of this laptop in the [Linux-Hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/?view=computers&type=notebook&vendor=ASUSTek%20Computer&model=K55VD) database. Looking at one of the probes ([#aa80e7c702](https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=aa80e7c702)) I can say that:

1. All devices are Linux-compatible (at least a free driver exists);
2. There are no critical errors in system logs collected in the probe.

So it's OK to power this laptop by Linux.